# Ideas for a Skills Matrix

Tags: skills

We are in the process of preparing a skill matrix for a relatively young IT organization. We have been going through some templates and still do not feel comfortable with what we have found. Basically, the idea is to have something less cumbersome to maintain and to cover all levels of the organization ( TechLead , Senior Software Engineers , Software Engineers so on). Does anyone have any innovative ideas to share in this regard ?

Comment: what is the skill matrix for?  To clearly separate the different grades/levels of experience?  Will it be used for performance reviews?

Comment: Programmer/Developer only or operations staff, too?

Comment: Only development staff for the moment.

Comment: While this question may have been on-topic at one point in the site's history, it would now be considered off-topic as a list-generating question without a canonical answer. It can be kept around as an historical artifact from PMSE's early days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you seen the [programmer competancy matrix](http://www.indiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/Programmer%20competency%20matrix.htm)? Maybe it'll prove useful.

Comment: Very good link :)

Comment: i like that one too.

Comment: Excellent link - it is both comprehensive and suitably geeky :-)

Comment: i think this is the best we can find as of now. we are going to base our matrix on this. thanks

Comment: Really awesome! It can also be used by developers for self evaluation and/or improvement.

Comment: Link-only answers often rot. Good answers on PMSE should contain some context and some attributed quotes to make the information accessible without having to chase down a link.

Answer (score 5):

I certainly see no need to try to reinvent the wheel. If the programmer competency matrix (as suggested in the answer from karunesh)is not a good fit, what about SFIA - Skills Framework for the Information Age - see http://www.sfia.org.uk/ which can be taken further in the shape of SFIA Plus - see also http://www.bcs.org/category/7852.